# My if/else statement is always executing else (android)

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-edittext

I am making an app to help me with something (It's quite hard to explain what it is) but it basically takes a 4 letter String from an EditText and outputs another String in the TextView. However the if/else statement is always executing the else even if the if statement is true. I will put my code below.

```
public class egkk extends ActionBarActivity {
        EditText editText;
        TextView textView;
        Button button;
        String aerodrome;
        String firstTwo;
        String firstThree;
        String first;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_egkk);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gen);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.egkk_edit);
                textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.s_view);

                aerodrome = editText.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
                firstTwo = aerodrome.substring(0, 1);
                firstThree = aerodrome.substring(0, 2);
                first = aerodrome.substring(0, 0);

                if (aerodrome.length() == 4){
                    if (aerodrome.equals("egkk")){
                        textView.setText("3750 - 3763: Gatwick APC general usage" + "3764 - 3767: Gatwick ADC circuit traffic and transits");
                    }
                    if (firstThree.equals("egj")){
                        textView.setText("Squawk is 7760 – 7775");
                    }
                    if (firstTwo.equals("eg")){
                        textView.setText("Sqauwk is 4301 - 4377");
                    }
                    if (firstTwo.equals("ei")){
                        textView.setText("Squawk is 4430 – 4477");
                    }
                    if (firstTwo.equals("lf")){
                        textView.setText("Squawk is 2201 – 2277");
                    }
                    if (firstTwo.equals("le")){
                        textView.setText("Squawk is 2201 – 2277");
                    }
                    if (firstTwo.equals("lp")){
                        textView.setText("Squawk is 2201 – 2277");
                    }
                    if (firstTwo.equals("fa")){
                        textView.setText("Squawk is 2201 – 2277");
                    }
                    if (firstTwo.equals("eh")){
                        textView.setText("Squawk is 7310 – 7677");
                    }
                    if (firstTwo.equals("eh")){
                        textView.setText("Squawk is 7310 – 7677");
                    }
                    if (first.equals("k")){
                        textView.setText("Squawk is 7610 – 7677");
                    }
                    if (first.equals("c")){
                        textView.setText("Squawk is 7610 – 7677");
                    }
                    if (firstTwo.equals("mu")){
                        textView.setText("Squawk is 7610 – 7677");
                    }
                    if (firstTwo.equals("my")){
                        textView.setText("Squawk is 7610 – 7677");
                    }
                    if (firstTwo.equals("mk")){
                        textView.setText("Squawk is 7610 – 7677");
                    }
                    if (firstTwo.equals("mt")){
                        textView.setText("Squawk is 7610 – 7677");
                    }
                    if (firstTwo.equals("md")){
                        textView.setText("Squawk is 7610 – 7677");
                    }
                    if (firstTwo.equals("tj")){
                        textView.setText("Squawk is 7610 – 7677");
                    }
                    if (firstTwo.equals("mu")){
                        textView.setText("Squawk is 7610 – 7677");
                    }
                    else {
                        textView.setText("Squawk is 1140 – 1177");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    textView.setText("Error");
                }
        }
    });



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_egkk, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Try to debug your code and see what value does aerodrome has after you assign it the value from the TextView

Comment: try to using aerodrome.length() >= 4 or aerodrome.length() <= 4 if it goes right then it depends on your condition

Comment: @RavindraPawar not need to do that, if the else clause is always executing `if (aerodrome.length() == 4){` is never true.... that's all

Answer (score 2):

This is because your condition:

```
if (aerodrome.length() == 4){
```

Never matches. This means, here, when you get the text, is never a String of 4 `length`.

```
aerodrome = editText.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Excuse me but this is obvious and the author of the question is asking why exactly does it not match

Comment: @GabriellaAngelova excused. But it's more obvious why it does not match.... Doesn't it? `editText` does not contain EXACTLY 4 chars...

Comment: To be exact, there needs to be the input and it's obvious the check is not satisfied that is why it moves to else

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was meaning the Squawk 1140 - 1177 is always executing, but I discovered why. To fix it i changed all of the ifs after the first one to else if and on the substring I had one less index by mistake so instead of

firstTwo = aerodrome.substring(0, 1);

I changed it to

firstTwo = aerodrome.substring(0, 2);

thanks for all your help though.